# How to match a whole word that includes special characters in regex

Tags: regex

In regex is there a way to escape special characters in an entire region of text in PCRE syntax?

eg. `hey+Im+A+Single+Word+Including+The+Pluses+And.Dots`

Normally to match the exact string in regex I would have to escape every single `+` and `.` with `/`s in the above string. This means that if the string is a variable, One has to seek for special characters and escape them manually. Is there an easier way to do this by telling regex escape all special characters in a block of text?

The motivation behind this is to append this to a larger regex so even though there are easier ways to get exact matches they don't apply here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: It may be worth noting that when using sed without extended regex (-r flag), `+` aren't recognized as meta-characters

Comment: @OganM, so what is the programming language?

Comment: It is R but syntax is perl. @revo's answer is what I was looking for

Comment: The syntax is exactly PCRE, `perl` is only the attribute name that can be used in Base R grep functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything between `\Q` and `\E` meta characters are treated as literals in PERL Compatible RegExes (PCRE). So in your case:

```
\Qhey+Im+A+Single+Word+Including+The+Pluses+And.Dots\E
```

Other engines rarely support this syntax.

Comment: Java's `Pattern` class also supports the `\Q…\E` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If it's python. you can use
re.escape(string) to get a literals string

```
import re

search = 'hey+Im+A+Single+Word+Including+The+Pluses+And.Dots'
text = '''hey+Im+A+Single+Word+Including+The+Pluses+And.Dots 
heyImmASingleWordIncludingThePlusessAndaDots 
heyImASingleWordIncludingThePlusesAndxDots 
'''
rc = re.escape(search)
#exactly first line in text
print(re.findall(rc,text))

#line two and three as it will + as repeat and . as any char
print(re.findall(search,text))
```

-------- result -------------------

['hey+Im+A+Single+Word+Including+The+Pluses+And.Dots']
['heyImmASingleWordIncludingThePlusessAndaDots', 'heyImASingleWordIncludingThePlusesAndxDots']